# Flutter - Dependency Injection

Tags: flutter, dependencies, code-injection

I am after some best practise tips for developing my Flutter app.

Currently, I have an app with multiple pages and multiple plugins such as network connection, SQLite, Location etc.

Currently, on each page, I am creating a new instance of each plugin I need access to as shown below, and then using the plugin functionality.

```
final _secureStorage = FlutterSecureStorage();
final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
```

What I want to achieve: I would like to possibly only create an instance of these classes once, and then be able to access the instance in all pages - something like `Dependency Injection`.

Currently, I am looking into `InheritedWidget` widget or the Provider package, however, I am not sure if they do what I am trying to achieve as I don't want to inherit or pass around widgets, I want to inject classes instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try out, the `get_it` package, since it is not tied to Flutter.

https://pub.dev/packages/get_it

Answer (score 0):

The [`ioc_container`](https://pub.dev/packages/ioc_container) may suit your case because it has [specific documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/ioc_container#add-firebase) on how to use it with Firebase and firebase Messaging. It does exactly as you say: initialize Firebase asynchronously and store the instances as singletons with dependency injection.

Here is a snippet of the code from the documentation:

```dart
extension FlutterFireExtensions on IocContainerBuilder {
  void addFirebase() {
    //These factories are all async because we need to ensure that Firebase is initialized
    addSingletonAsync(
      (container) {
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

        return Firebase.initializeApp(
          options: container.get<FirebaseOptions>(),
        );
      },
    );
    addSingletonAsync(
      (container) async => FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(
        app: await container.getAsync<FirebaseApp>(),
      ),
    );
    addSingletonAsync(
      (container) async => FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(
        app: await container.getAsync<FirebaseApp>(),
      ),
    );
    addSingletonAsync((container) async {
      //Ensure we have already initialized Firebase
      await container.getAsync<FirebaseApp>();

      return FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    });
  }
}
```